# iPhone iPad universal app - how big is final file for devices?

Tags: iphone, ipad

If I have 300 640 x 960 images (for iPhone 4) and 300 1024 x 768 images for iPad, and I want to make a universal app, does the installed app on the iPhone include all the iPad specific images and vice-versa?

Seems like on many apps it would greatly increase the installed application size on different devices.

Comment: "Universal" gives it a way really, it will include ALL images.

Comment: Try it and see, but removing resources will generally invalidate the code signature, preventing it from being installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A universal app is a single application by definition, so it will include all your images.

Comment: And Apple will reject apps if they have the same content, so distributing as 2 separate apps doesn't work either.  I was only asking wondering if iTunes would only copy over the necessary files for the device.

Comment: But both apps wouldn't have the same content -- one would have larger images than the other. As for iTunes -- what exactly are you expecting it to do? It just downloads application bundles. Nothing in iTunes or the entire distribution model will somehow selectively download content automatically. You'd have to code that in your app.